# するだろうな wonderment or a question?

Tags: translation, meaning, word-choice

If a person says " レイどんな顔をするだろうな"

Is it more correct to translate it as:

1. I wonder what face Rey would make.

Or

2. How do you think he will react?

Answer (score 1):

"レイどんな顔をするだろうな" sounds soliloquy. So I think 1 is more correct.